# Convert a PEM certificate to a PKCS12 format

Tags: mongodb, openssl, certificate

I have a PEM format which need to be convert it to PKCS12 format .Below command  is used to convert but convertion is not happening .Can anyone please help me

openssl pkcs12 -export C:\sample keyStore.p12 -inkey server.pem C:\sample server.pem

Answer (score 1):

You need a certificate file as well as a (private) key file.

As a sample we generate a new private key with the RSA algorithm:

```sh
openssl genrsa -f4 -out ".\private.key" 2048
```

Next we creat a certificate based on the key:

```sh
openssl req -x509 -new -key ".\private.key" -out ".\certificate.pem"
```

Last we merge both piles into the PFX/PKCS#12:

```sh
openssl pkcs12 -inkey .\private.key -in .\certificate.pem -export -out .\certificateWithKey.pfx
```